# MSTest - Integration tests - use value of another test

Tags: integration-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2022

I know that unit tests should run isolated and should never depend on other unit tests.
However, I also write some ***integration tests*** with MSTest and sometimes they produce a result that I would like to reuse in another test.

For example:

1. Creating a user
2. Searching this user from the database
3. Deleting the user

Each of those points would be an integration test for me, so I would like to write methods that look like this:

```
    User _myNewUser;
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateAUserTest() 
    {
        //User gets created here somehow....
        _myNewUser = successfullyCreatedUser;
    }
```

And this test should run after the preceeding test:

```
    User _myNewUser;
    [TestMethod]
    public void SearchingUserTest() 
    {
        var user = searchUser(_newUser.GetName());
        //Assert that user is not null
    }
```

You can see that I use the value of the first test in the second test.
With a playlist I could make sure that both tests run in the correct order.

However, in VS 2022 each test gets executed in isolation, so what I am trying to do does not work.
_newUser is always null if I run the second test, even if the first test was a success.

1. Is my idea bad in general?
2. If not: How can I use the produced data of a test in another test?

Answer (score 0):

I usually extract the contents of a test like that into a separate staging function that does not contain the [TestMethod] attribute, so that I can reuse it to stage other tests.

```
private void Stage_CreateAUser()
{
   //do work from CreateAUserTest()
}

[TestMethod]
public void CreateAUserTest()
{
   Stage_CreateAUser();
}

private void Stage_SearchingUser()
{
   //do work from CreateAUserTest()
}

[TestMethod]
public void SearchingUserTest()
{
   Stage_CreateAUser();
   Stage_SearchingUser();
}
```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly best to keep your tests independent, so changing one test won't break others.

If you need some kind of setup/preparation before your test can run, I'd advise you to do that as part of the test itself, instead of relying on other tests.